# Radio button checked with Html.RadioButtonFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

```
<%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AmortizationTermInYears, true, new { propertyName = "AmortizationTermInYears", onchange = "showAmortizationTermInYears();UpdateField(this);", amortizationTermInYearsRadio = "true" })%>
```

How do I tell this helper to check this radio button. I tried adding `true` after the `true` I already specified (which is the value not the `isChecked`) paramater, but that didn't compile, it said no `RadioButtonFor()` definition has those 4 parameters specified.

Comment: add tag in your question with tag C# or ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AmortizationTermInYears, true, 
         new { 
              propertyName = "AmortizationTermInYears", 
              onchange = "showAmortizationTermInYears();UpdateField(this);", 
              amortizationTermInYearsRadio = "true",
              checked="checked"
             }
     )
%>
```

Comment: @slandau Try `@checked` instead of `checked`,
"checked" is a C# keyword so you mus use `@` sign before it (similar to setting class by `@class`)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
_checked="checked"
```

this used to work before. But later on they
 `@class = "checked"` has become more of regular use.